# Cube texturing as a sphere in UV editor

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm new to blender. I'm trying to texture a cube and when try to scale a single face, it scales all of them as if it was a sphere. I also selected all the faces and pressed U then selected cube projection, but I don't want that, I want to have those separate faces. I would appreciate a solution step by step. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate the *Proportional Editing* option in the *UV Editor* (or press <kbd>O</kbd>), also if you want to have separate faces, mark the seam where you want to separate the faces (in the 3D view, in *Edit* mode, select the edges and press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Mark Seam* then unwrap)